# What is the best way to centralize TempData success / error messages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, tempdata

At this moment almost every controller method will return success / error messages with TempData to the view like this:

```
if (result) {
    TempData["messageSuccess"] = "Some nice success message";
} else {
    TempData["messageError"] = "Some nice error message";
}
```

I want to centralize this functionality somewhere in a simple method which is callable from anywhere in the application (controllers), **so what is the best way to centralize this into a method which can be reused?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension for the controller. Add the below method in one of your static `UtilityClass`.

```
  public static void SetTempDataMessages(this Controller controller, bool result)
  {
     if (result) 
     {
        controller.TempData["messageSuccess"] = "Some nice success message";
     } 
     else 
     {
        controller.TempData["messageError"] = "Some nice error message";
     }
  }
```

Then in your action method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = true;
    this.SetTempDataMessages(result);
    return View();
}
```

You can pass the success and error messages as parameters as well. (But I personally think this is unnecessary and you should keep your TempData in your ActionMethods)